# Normal Map baking gives different results than 2.79

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I bake normals on a regular basis and have noticed a considerable change in the result of baking normal maps from 2.79 to 2.8. Does anyone know why? The node setup and groups are exactly the same as in 2.79 yet the result is very different.

**2.79**
[image: 2.79 Normal Map]

**2.8**
[image: 2.8 Normal Map]

**2.8 Object Space Displacement Node**
This is the result when running everything through a displacement node before going into the output node
[image: 2.8 Object Space Displacement Node]

**2.8 World Space Displacement Node**
[image: 2.8 World Space Displacement Node]

**2.8 Bump Node**
This is the result when running everything through a bump node before going into the output node. It's obviously not the way to go but I included it just in case.
[image: 2.8 Bump Node]